# How to call the_author_meta and make it work?

Tags: php, loop

I am developing an author badge for my Wordpress site and I am learning how to call meta functions (needs to be within The Loop). The meta functions that I am calling are author bio related, like username, last name etc

Here is a code example:

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    About <?php the_author(); ?>, the author of this blog
    <?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?>
    <?php get_the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I added this example to my author.php file and it worked, however it displayed the same thing multiple times (hence the loop). How do I actually do this if I want to call meta functions in Wordpress and not have them echoed multiple times like this?

I am certain that I am doing this incorrectly and there is a correct way of achieving it.

If you choose to reply, please be detailed as my knowledge of PHP coding is to the extend that I learned what echo is *today*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your author meta information after if ( have_posts() ) :

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    About <?php the_author(); ?>, the author of this blog
    <?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?>
    <?php echo get_the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?>

<?php rewind_posts();

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<?php //loop stuff  ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I copy and pasted your code into my author.php and it didn't return with the called meta functions. Are you sure that you wrote that correctly?

Comment: I forgot to add the_post(); to queue up the first post.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly, I have just one question before I accept this as correct. Is there any better way of doing this or is this the best practice to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: If you want to get the author stuff outside the loop you can assign a `$variable = get_queried_object();`  then use $varibale->display_name, $variable->description; instead but the code I used in the answer is they way the twentytwelve theme does it so I would say it's "best practices"